# Can you email different sections to different people from one form created in infopath and submitted to sharepoint?

Tags: infopath

So for example I have 3 sections, and each person has a complaint box (regular text box) and a person responsible (contact selector). Now when I submit the form, how do I get each sections to email the person specified by the person responsible?

I am using Infopath 2007 along with Sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only looking for people to be emailed the text, instead of opening the form to a specific view, then I would just make sure those fields are promoted to library columns.  At that point, you can use a simple SPD Workflow that sends three emails each send to the selected person, the specified text.

Comment: +1 been there done that

Comment: ok, I haven't really used SPD but i'll be giving it a shot, thanks!